# How to find the value of control within a gridView from Client side using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, gridview

I have a GridView, I want to find the Value of a Control based on its id at Client Side using javascript. I have the index of row which I'm clicking. Now I want to find the Value of a Column which has a label in same row.

```
     function OnClientClickReplaceRewardRuleFile(link) {

            var row = link.parentNode.parentNode;
            var rowIndex = row.rowIndex - 1;
//            alert("RowIndex: " + rowIndex);
            var lbl = document.getElementById('<%=GridViewMultiplePOSAssociationId.Rows[rowIndex].FindControl("LabelStatusPendingPOSId").ClientID %>');
            alert(lbl);
            return false;
}
```

Its not working.

aspx code.

```
   <asp:TemplateField HeaderStyle-Width="80px" ItemStyle-Width="250px" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center"
                                       HeaderText="Action">
                                       <ItemTemplate>
                                           <asp:LinkButton ID="HyperLinkAssociate" CommandArgument='<%#Eval("POS Id") %>'
                                               CommandName="Associate" Text="Associate" runat="server" OnClientClick="return OnClientClickAssociateRewardRuleFile(this);" CausesValidation="false"></asp:LinkButton>/<asp:LinkButton
                                                   ID="HyperLinkReplace" CommandArgument='<%#Eval("POS Id") %>' CommandName="Replace"
                                                   Text="Replace" runat="server" OnClientClick="return OnClientClickReplaceRewardRuleFile(this);" CausesValidation="false"></asp:LinkButton>
                                       </ItemTemplate>
                                   </asp:TemplateField >
```

I have tried this:

```
 function OnClientClickReplaceRewardRuleFile(link) {
            var row = link.parentNode.parentNode;
        var rowIndex = row.rowIndex - 1;
        var table = document.getElementById('<%=GridViewMultiplePOSAssociationId.ClientID %>');

        var lbls = document.getElementsByTagName('label');
        var spans = document.getElementsByTagName('span');

        for (var i = 0; i < lbls.length; i++) {
            if (lbls[i].id.indexOf('LabelStatusPendingPOSId') > 0) {
                if (rowIndex == i) {
                    if (lbls[i].innerText == 'Applied') {
                        alert('Action cannot be completed for this POS.');
                        return false;
                    }
                    break;
                }

            }
        }

        for (var i = 0; i < spans.length; i++) {
            if (spans[i].id.indexOf('LabelStatusPendingPOSId') > 0) {
                if (rowIndex == i) {
                    if (spans[i].innerText == 'Applied') {
                        alert('Action cannot be completed for this POS.');
                        return false;
                    }
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
  function OnClientClickReplaceRewardRuleFile(link) {
        var row = link.parentNode.parentNode;
        var table = document.getElementById('<%=GridView1.ClientID %>');

        var lbls = document.getElementsByTagName('label');
        var spans = document.getElementsByTagName('span');

        for (var i = 0; i < lbls.length; i++) {
            if (lbls[i].id.indexOf('LabelStatusPendingPOSId') > 0) {
                alert(lbls[i]);
                break;
            }
        }

        for (var i = 0; i < spans.length; i++) {
            if (spans[i].id.indexOf('LabelStatusPendingPOSId') > 0) {
                alert(spans[i]);
                break;
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: what should I write in place of yourlabelname?

Comment: you should write LabelStatusPendingPOSId

Comment: you got an alert that means the code found the label/span named "LabelStatusPendingPOSId". try the code again i have modified it

Comment: How will I get the Text of this Label?

Comment: replace alert(lbls[i]) with alert(lbls[i].innerHTML). Do the same for alert(spans[i]). Mark as solved if this solves you question

Comment: use innerText instead of innerHTML

Comment: Sorry, I have updated the question. Please see this.

Comment: What do you get in alerts?